# How to get lyrics for currently playing song on spotify app?

Tags: spotify

I would like to learn lyrics of songs playing on spotify but not every author gives them permission to publish it I guess.

I'd like to read the currently playing song and get the lyrics from some service.

Do I need some library from their [documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/android/) or is there just some available intent?

If there is already some nice app, you can point me in comments ;D

Comment: While the overall question seems on-topic, please note that app development is off-topic since Android Enthusiasts focuses on end-users or power-users (but not necessarily developers) solving their issues, so we can't help with SDK library or code-related issues.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't sure what is the scope of this exchange. I found that on spotify app there is option for allowing others app to see currently playing song. I found [SimpleLyrics](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.igorvd.lyrics&gl=US) finally. If somebody knows better apps feel free to add.